# Android : Display Lock Screen top of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm displaying activity on top of lock screen using the following flags in  `onCreate()`

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

And the activity is displayed properly.When User press Power Button i do not want activity shown on top of lock screen. How do i do this ? TIA.

Comment: Add dynamic receiver to listen screen-off action and then remove flag_show_when_locked from activity.

Comment: But screen off does not mean phone will be locked...and i am killing this activity it will be minimized on back key pressed.