# Activate Device Admin in android

Tags: android, device, administrator

I am using this code to activate Device Admin in android.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, demoDeviceAdmin);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "Your boss told you to do this");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
```

[image]

But I want this screen above screen lock. Means I dont have to unlock my screen to get this option.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981950/android-display-lock-screen-top-of-activity

Comment: That link does not provides the solution i need. Can u guide me through?

Comment: this is what i was looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701928/disable-lock-screen